# deploying webpage to github where html file is in templates folder

Tags: python, flask, github, github-pages

I am attempting to deploy a webpage to github pages where the index.html file is not in the root directory, but in the templates folder. As a result, I keep getting a 404 error page whenever I try to access the url. how can I upload a webpage where the html file is not in the root of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub Pages is a fairly limited hosting service, although nice for what it does. Is there a particular reason why you can't simply move index.html to the root directory? I know these things can be a pain, but I believe the parser that GHP uses is pretty strict about this.

Comment: Well I am currently using the Jinja Template due to me using Python and Flask in my application. If I moved the index.html file out of the, "templates" folder, it would crash the whole application

Comment: Okay, so, it sounds like you're trying to deploy a non-static application to GitHub Pages. That won't work regardless - GitHub Pages is for static content.

Comment: @azan_bade You can use some cloud hosting service like heroku or pythonanywhere to deploy your website